# implement raw_input in my algorithm

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm just a newbie on Python.
I have this algorithm to see is a word is a palindrome or not.

```
def isPalindrome(s):

    def toChars(s):
        s = s.lower()
        ans = ''
        for c in s:
            if c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
                ans = ans + c
        return ans

    def isPal(s):
        if len(s) <= 1:
            return True
        else:
            return s[0] == s[-1] and isPal(s[1:-1])

    return isPal(toChars(s))
```

And I want to implement something like this:

```
s=str(raw_input('Enter a word with quotes: '))
```

I want to be asked for entering a word, because now, the only way to run my code is to call it in a shell.

P.S.: Sorry for my English.

Comment: `toChars` has a prime candidate for a list comprehension: `return [c for c in s if c in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']`. Also, you might want `string.lowercase` (which may contain á, depending on locale).

Comment: Please don't edit your question to ask something totally different. I've just rolled back to the question the answers below actually are responding to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do it (without quotes -- I am not sure why you'd want them):

```
s = raw_input('Enter a word: ')
print isPalindrome(s)
```

Comment: Thanks! But in fact the print statement must be:print isPalindrome(s)

Answer (score 0):

This would do

```
>>> is_a_pal = raw_input('Enter a word with quotes: ')
Enter a word with quotes: tyuiyt
>>> is_a_pal
'tyuiyt'
>>>
```